# I have got a error that "comment cannot be blank" could u solve this solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```js
unlApp.Social.postCmtText = function (postdata)
{
    var cPage = $.mobile.activePage;
    var cmnt_text = cPage.find(".comment_textarea").val().trim();
    if (cmnt_text.length === 0) 
    {
        alert("Comment cannot be empty");
    }
    }
```

```html
        <div class="cmts_footer" data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
            <div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Write your comment" class="cmttextarea comment_textarea"></div>
            <div class="send_img_btn">
                <img class="send_cmnt_btn arrow" src="img/arrows.png" alt="send" onclick="commentSendbtn(this);" />

                <img class="cmntpostloadimg loadbar" src="img/commentsloading.gif" alt="loading..." />

            </div>
        </div>
```

error i have received comments cannnot be blank
please could any one let me know what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

`.comment_textarea` is a (contenteditable) div. Its content will be its text, not its value per se.

Try changing:

```
var cmnt_text = cPage.find(".comment_textarea").val().trim();
```

with:

```
var cmnt_text = cPage.find(".comment_textarea").text().trim();
```